# SQL Server with 'AlwaysOn' feature - does it make partition tolerant on CAP theorem?

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

If we configure 'AlwaysOn' feature in SQL Server and create multiple replicas (synchronous and asynchronous) - does this make it become partition-tolerant in the CAP theorem?

Why RDBMS on CAP theorem are always depicted as CA?

Comment: because MySQL also allows you to create read replicas. And that makes is distributed and partition tolerance came into play.

Comment: Makes sense, will edit that. Thanks for pointing out. But does this question deserve down vote?